How to Encrypt / Decrypt User Data via a Polkadot Compatible Wallet using the keys stored there?
In my Polkadot-based decentralized application, I need to allow users to decrypt their own encrypted data using their private keys managed by wallets (e.g., Talisman, SubWallet, or Polkadot.js). However, these wallets don’t seem to provide direct decryption APIs.
What is the best way to achieve user data decryption securely while ensuring. Private keys remain managed by the wallet and never exposed. Are there any existing solutions or best practices for handling such use cases?

Is the data volume large?
